# WebForms redirect page request for same page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7.5

Webforms using VB.NET.  I have a page a.aspx that exists within a web app.  I want to replace that page (with my own modified version) and call a new page b.aspx, but still call a.aspx if I need to.  By design I cannot rename or change existing links in the application to a.aspx (out of my control).

Can I, using some sort of re-writing IIS module (or something more practical), create a new a.aspx that checks some server variable, if that is true then redirect to b.aspx, otherwise redirect to the original a.aspx, bypassing my code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, and you can solve it by using a Session variable. Something like:

```
If Session("YourVariableHere") = Nothing Then
    Server.Transfer("b.aspx", True)
End If
```

Use this on your page A load.

Comment: I would need to redirect to a.aspx, in this case, if the variable is set.  i.e redirect to a page with the same name

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Could you please be more clear about what your end goal is. The question and this comment are both quite difficult to understand.